# Possible to have repeat values of ph_label?

Tags: officer

Is it possible to have repeat values of ph_label within the same slide of a ppt document created with officer?  Seems like i shouldn't be able to, but the document I'm working with right now has repeat values.  Makes it really difficult to properly put things on the slide! Has anyone else seen this?  Is the only workaround to use type and id?

Answer (score 1):

Repeat values of ph_label occur when a content placeholder has been copied and pasted within the same slide.  Using ph_label in your pt_with functions is much more preferable than using type.  To fix this problem, I went back and chanced the Master Slide templates.